# AngularJS $http GET comma separated query string parameters

Tags: angularjs, http, get, google-drive-api, query-string

I'm trying to do a HTTP GET call using Angular's $http. I've written a generic function like this,

```
function doGETRequest(url, params) {
      return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: baseURL + url,
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
        },
        params: params
      });
    }
```

I want to create a URL like this,
`https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/about?fields=quotaBytesTotal%2CquotaBytesUsed%2CrootFolderId%2Cuser` but I cannot for the life of me figure out the query param part. So far I tried the following:

```
 doGETRequest('/about', {fields:'user,quotaBytesTotal,quotaBytesUsed,rootFolderId'})


doGETRequest('/about', {fields:['user','quotaBytesTotal','quotaBytesUsed','rootFolderId']})


doGETRequest('/about', {fields:encodeURIComponent('user,quotaBytesTotal,quotaBytesUsed,rootFolderId')})
```

It does work for the second one, but it parses it as `https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/about?fields=user&fields=quotaBytesTotal&fields=quotaBytesUsed&fields=rootFolderId` and Google just sends response for the first query and ignores the rest (as expected).

So the question is how do I pass comma separated values in query params? Do I have to manually write URL encoded values? Doesn't this beat the purpose of having a params field?

Comment: the second one should work, it should be handled in the web-service

Comment: Web-Service handler in question is Google, so...Any other ideas?

Comment: sorry, can you post what is your expected url ?

Comment: It's in the question, but here you go: https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/about?fields=quotaBytesTotal%2CquotaBytesUsed%2CrootFolderId%2Cuser

Comment: you mean the 1st one didnt work ? ( i think that should work ) another way is just change the **url: baseURL +'&'+ params** -> params = 'fields=quotaBytesTotal,quotaBytesUsed,rootFolderId,user'

Comment: I'm writing a generic function so that I can use this across the project irrespective of the values. Now using the code you suggested beats the purpose of using $http's inbuilt methods no?  Also, it doesn't work.

Comment: @kiro112, thanks for your input. I've posted a couple of solutions. Do check if you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, for those who stumbled upon the same problem as I did, I found two ways of solving this.

**First**, as @kiro112 suggested in the comments, I write the params directly in the URL. Since $http doesn't encode the URL it'll work. So the code will be something like

```
doGETRequest('/about?fields='+encodeURIComponent("user,quotaBytesTotal,quotaBytesUsed,rootFolderId"))
```

and we'll have to get rid of the `params` part in the `doGetRequest()` method. Personally, I don't like this one as it beats the purpose of having the params part in $http.

**Second** method is overriding the default `$httpParamSerializer` and supplying our own. To do that, the `doGetRequest()`  method has to be modified like so,

```
function doGETRequest(url, params) {
      return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: baseURL + url,
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +access_token
        },
        params: params,
        paramSerializer: function (value){
          return Object.keys(value)+'='+encodeURIComponent(Object.values(value));
        }
      });
    }
```

What happens here is, we do not let angular encode the params. Let me tell you why. As per the [docs here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializer), angular only does encoding like so,

- `{'foo': 'bar'}` results in `foo=bar`
- `{'foo': Date.now()}` results in `foo=2015-04-01T09%3A50%3A49.262Z` (`toISOString()` and encoded representation of a Date object)
- `{'foo': ['bar', 'baz']}` results in `foo=bar&foo=baz` (repeated key for each array element)
- `{'foo': {'bar':'baz'}}` results in `foo=%7B%22bar%22%3A%22baz%22%7D"` (stringified and encoded representation of an object)

Whereas we require something in the lines of `{'foo':['bar', 'baz']}` resulting in `foo=bar%2Cbaz`. So we override the `paramSerializer` and write our own serializer.

The second approach looks much cleaner to me as far as using generic methods is concerned. However, I am still on a look out for a better option.

Comment: have a look at github.com/pinoyyid/ngDrive